# Fly effect in extension is it possible?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension which will show selected text in popup.html,

when click the extension icon it should give a flying effect,

Please see the sample below,

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/file/jbasket/fly-to-basket/

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't supply any api to let the icon "fly".

But you can simulate the effect through contentScript:http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html.

When you click the icon,you can run the contentScript,which will add a image into current page.This image is the same with the icon,and it's position is below the icon(you can't make the just below the icon).Then you can let the image fly as you expect(use jQuery or any libary).

Comment: I need to fly a popup box to the extension Icon.It should show animation then fade into extension Icon when again clicked same action should occur,is tht possible?

Comment: Sorry,it's impossible.Chrome doesn't supply such api.